# What is the new preferred approach to running code before and after activity finishes with ActivityScenarioRule?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, androidx-test

Previously with [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule), one was able to override [beforeActivityLaunched](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#beforeActivityLaunched()) and [afterActivityFinished](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#afterActivityFinished()) to control app state before and after all tests (e.g, implementing a custom rule Class that extended [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#beforeActivityLaunched()) that would be used in all tests). With [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule) marked `final` and without these `protected` methods, where/how is this logic now moved to with regard to how one controls before and after an activity? What's the recommended approach now if one were to write a custom rule to be applied to all tests?